# URL parameter is getting modified

Tags: java, spring-boot

I wrote a micro-service to make `http call` to an `API` and then fetch data via Angular 7. Code is as given below.
**`Connector Application`**

```
package com.ajay.dashboard.service;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DellDashboardConnectorApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DellDashboardConnectorApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {

        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

**`Connector Controller`**

```
package com.ajay.dashboard.service.controller;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;

/*
 * Created by Kulkaa
 */

@RestController
public class DellDashboardController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DellDashboardController.class);

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/incident", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> retrieveAllCircles(HttpServletRequest request) {
        logger.info("DellDashboardController -> retrieveAllIncidents : invoked.");

        String formUrl = "https://<api>/api/now/table/incident";

        final String sysparm_query = "incident_stateNOT%20IN6%2C7%5Eassignment_group%3D4122c7f8f09cc1002283ac3a043ae3e6";
        final String sysparm_display_value = "true";
        final String sysparm_exclude_reference_link = "true";
        try {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            URI actualUrl = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(formUrl).buildAndExpand(params).toUri();
            actualUrl = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(actualUrl).queryParam("sysparm_query", sysparm_query)
                    .queryParam("sysparm_display_value", sysparm_display_value)
                    .queryParam("sysparm_exclude_reference_link", sysparm_exclude_reference_link)
                    .build().toUri();
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.add("Authorization", "<authorization code>");
            headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
            return restTemplate.exchange(actualUrl, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return retrieveAllCircles(request);

    }

}
```

When I run this as a `Spring boot app` in tomcat, `incident_stateNOT%20IN6%2C7%5Eassignment_group%3D4122c7f8f09cc1002283ac3a043ae3e6` gets modified as `incident_stateNOT%2520IN6%252C7%255Eassignment_group%253D4122c7f8f09cc1002283ac3a043ae3e6`. Because of this unwanted modification, I'm unable to connect to my API. I'm unable to figure out what is causing this modification. What is causing this modification?

P.S: `mvn clean install` runs perfectly without any errors.

Comment: Yes, `sysparm_query` will be URL encoded. That's a good thing.

Comment: But I don't understand how it gets modified while running the micro-service...

Comment: You're getting double URL encoding. Determine why.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

The URL is being url-encoded by one of the libraries you're using, `sysparm_query` is already url-encoded, so you're getting `%` changed `%25` and so on. So you probably want to change `sysparm_query` to not be url-encoded yet.

Comment: Okay, so I added this line: `String final_sysparm_query = URLEncoder.encode(sysparm_query, "UTF-8");`

Comment: Isn't that going to make it even worse by adding another layer of encoding? Seems like you want to decode instead.

Comment: Then I can use `URIBuilder` which can take parameters as it is.

Answer (score 0):

The `%25` means that there is an ASCII character of `hex(25)` code - it is the `%` character.

It is correct behavior because you have in the `sysparm_query`: "incident_stateNOT%20IN...", and the `%` character was encoded as `%25` to send it through the url parameters.

Comment: But I don't want to send `%25`. I want to send `%2`

Comment: On the other side the `%25` should be encoded back to the `%`.